# How Can we implement MARS kind of functionality in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

Previously i working on SQL Server 2005 and i used MARS functionality but currently i am working on a old project and they want SQL Server 2000 as a backend.. and i want MARS kind of functionality in it.. please tell me how can i do this.. frontend is (VB.NET)

Comment: you might want to remind the client that Mainstream support for SQL Server 2000 Service Pack 4 (SP4) ended on April 8, 2008 !!

Comment: The Extended Support End Date for  SQL Server 2000 Service Pack 4 (SP4) is 04/09/2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored proc can return multiple result sets that can be handled in client code.

Would this achieve the same result?

This also has the advantage of reducing round trips to the database

Answer (score 1):

True MARS, no. You cannot execute a request while another request is still active in SQL 2000. You can bind multiple sessions into a single transaction and execute multiple requests from different sessions using sp_getbindtoken and sp_bindsession but each session has to execute one request, finish it and *then* a new session can execute a request on the same transaction, which is not what MARS is like.

Perhaps you can detail what you try to accomplish that you need MARS for. Perhaps you can substitute [client side cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266531%28VS.60%29.aspx) for your needs?